# Flask/Python, I can't get values returned by my json on my jinja2 template

Tags: json

I am sorry to disturb you but I am new to Python and Flask and I am working on a To Do list website.
I use the MVC architecture.
I am encountering an issue during some hours to display the list of my tasks.

I am trying to get the name of the task to make a list of all tasks. But I have this when I try to display all tasks list. I Know that jsonify return a Response but I am really confused...
I have tried to use json.dumps but without success...

This is what I got on the website, a response 200 ():

Thank you :D !

[image]

This is the model for my tasks and my display_task func

```
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM task;")
        db_linkage.commit()
        #data = {"test": 123456789, "test2": 2, "test3": 3}
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return jsonify(task=data)
```

This is the controller for my tasks

```
def task_list(data):
        title = TaskModel.display_task(data)
        return render_template("tasks/list.html", title="test",
                           myContent="test", task=title)
```

This is my list.html

```
{% include "partials/header.html" %}
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <h4 style="text-align: center">
                Liste des tâches
            </h4>
            <p>{{ task }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% include "partials/footer.html" %}
```

And this is my database scheme:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of all rows in your DB, thus there isn't any need to jsonify the data. Instead, you could get the data and parse it to get your required format.